# donut chart using json array

Tags: javascript, d3.js, donut-chart

I am learning d3 and trying to make use d3 library in my application for showing some visualization chart .i am getting data through web api in the form of json here.

**My script:**

```
var data=  "rows":[
    {
        "STATUS" : "Active",
        "count" : "246"  
    },
    {
        "STATUS" : "Not Proceeded With",
        "count" : "40" 
    }
]

var width = 800,
    height = 250,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(radius - 70);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function (d) {
    return d.count;
});

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
    .data(pie(data.rows))
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc");

g.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("fill", function (d) {
        return color(d.data.rows.STATUS);
    });

g.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function (d) {
        return d.data.rows.STATUS;
    });
```

Now i want to use that data set for creating the donut chart.i have tried but not getting success.can any one plz suggest me any idea how i can do

Comment: Show us the javascript code you tried.

Comment: i have mentioned the script above

Comment: can u plz tell me where i m doing mistake ?

Comment: Sorry for off topic but have you tried C3.js ? Its a D3 based chart. Take a lot (http://c3js.org/samples/chart_donut.html)

Comment: No i didn't heard about C3.Js...?can u plz help me in d3 ..actually i know i am doing very small mistake ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple problems:

1.) Your JSON isn't valid:

```
var data = { //<- missing bracket
  "rows": [
    {
      "STATUS": "Active",
      "count": "246"
    }, {
      "STATUS": "Not Proceeded With",

      "count": "40"
    }
  ]
} //<- missing bracket
```

2.) You are not accessing the STATUS attribute correctly for your fill and text label:

```
return color(d.data.STATUS); //<-- don't need "rows", you only passed in data.rows
```

Here is is working nicely:

```js
var data= { "rows":[

  {
   "STATUS" : "Active",
"count" : "246"  
  }
 ,   
  {
   "STATUS" : "Not Proceeded With",

"count" : "40" 
  }

   ]};

var width = 800,
    height = 250,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(radius - 70);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function (d) {
    return d.count;
});



var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
        .data(pie(data.rows))
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "arc");

    g.append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .style("fill", function (d) {
        return color(d.data.STATUS);
    });

    g.append("text")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
    })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function (d) {
        return d.data.STATUS;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Mark..Thanks a lot mark for your suitable help i really appreciate for that ..:)